# Invalid format while compiling CSS using node-sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass, node-sass, scss-mixins

I am getting an error while making my page responsive.
I am using @mixin to make that possible.

```
@mixin mediaSm{
  @mixin screen and (max-width:768px) {
    @content;

  }
}

@mixin mediaMd{
  @mixin screen and (max-width:500px) {
    @content;

  }
}
@mixin mediaLg{
  @mixin screen (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1170px) {
    @content;

  }
}
@mixin mediaSm{
  @mixin screen and (min-width:500px) {
    @content;

  }
}
```

I am getting an error which says that the format is wrong and there should be '{'after 'and'.
I am using Ubuntu, but the same code does not show a kind of error in Windows 10.

> {   "status": 1,   "file":
>   "/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_portfolio/scss/_config.scss",   "line": 34,
>   "column": 10,   "message": "Invalid CSS after \"  @mixin screen\":
>   expected \"{\", was \"and (max-width:768p\"",   "formatted": "Error:
>   Invalid CSS after \"  @mixin screen\": expected \"{\", was \"and
>   (max-width:768p\"\n        on line 34 of scss/_config.scss\n    from
>   line 1 of scss/main.scss\n>>   @mixin screen and
>   (max-width:768px){\n\n   ---------^\n" }

Comment: `@mixin screen....` should be `@media screen`....?

Comment: oo.. damn...u are correct...thx man.